# HTML select and option mixed directions (ltr & rtl)

Tags: html, css, html-select, direction

I have a select box that I want to be aligned to the right, but I want to keep the options dropdown aligned to the left. Like so:

```
<select>
  <option>item</option>
</select>
```

And the CSS:

```
select { direction: rtl; }
option { direction: ltr; }
```

But setting the direction of the select tag also sets the direction of the select dropdown menu. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwEEQ/6/)

Is this even possible?  I know that I could, as an alternative, build a custom select functionality with js, but I'd like to keep it simple if I can.

Comment: Can you post a picture mentioning what you want?

Comment: I updated the fiddle to maybe explain it better.  I want the selected option right justified, and the options that appear on clicking the select to be left justified.

Comment: Identifiers can't start with numbers. Therefore, `.1` is a wrong selector. You should escape it: `.\000031`.

Comment: Right.  I whipped up a quick example, should have looked at it further, but as  you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwEEQ/17/) that with proper css selecting the situation persists.

Comment: Same problem, seems it's a problem of browser compatibility
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787734/select-with-direction-rtl-doesnt-work-on-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`direction: rtl;` is not exactly text alignment. Or to be precise text alignment is a side effect of direction. Note that direction also affects position of the dropdown arrow in your setup.

Conventional browsers **do not allow you to style select element** (it looks significantly different on different platforms, especially mobiles).

In [Sciter](http://www.terrainformatica.com/sciter/) you can style `<select>` parts individually as select components are normal DOM elements there:

```
select > caption { text-align:right; } 
select > button { ... } 
select > popup > option { text-align:left; }
```

I've made it possible as Sciter is designed specifically for desktop UI and `<select>` styling is a must there.

As a solution for plain web pages I would suggest to use `<select>` substitutes like http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Comment: Yea, I came to that conclusion as well:  to use select alternatives since they're really not that difficult to make.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your fiddle is that you use

```
.1 {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

However, identifiers can't start with numbers. Therefore, `.1` is a wrong selector. You should escape it: `.\000031`.

Then, if you use...

```
.\000031 {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

...it works as you want, at least on Firefox 37.

Note other browsers may not allow you to style `select` elements.

```css
#ex-1 {
    direction: rtl;
    width: 120px;
}
.\000031 {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<select id="ex-1">
    <option class='1'>item one</option>
    <option class='1'>item two</option>
    <option class='1'>item three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Interesting, but as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwEEQ/17/) that with correct css selecting the issue persists.  I'm inclined to not use select's at all unless they don't need to be styled... A little javascript and some div's and it can be done pretty easily & with much more flexibility.