# Select with direction rtl doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I want to make a select that opens from right to left.

This is what I see with Google Chrome (correct)

[image: Chrome]

And this is what I take with Firefox (error)

[image: Firefox]

Here is the code and the example: http://jsfiddle.net/nxTTd/65/`...`

How can I fix it?

Comment: I assume Firefox is correct because first word is `select` and not `Prima` in `RTL`.

Comment: I need the result as Chrome, so how can i have that result?

Comment: Why not just use some jQuery plugin for custom dropdown?

Comment: @Justinas if possible i want to use only css for some problems of compatibility with jquery (old pages with some restriction), but if it's not possible how can i do with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

It's arguable which of these is correct. They're both doing the same thing except that while Chrome anchors the text to the left-hand side, Firefox anchors it to the right. I see that your `<option>` elements are set to `ltr` so I can see why you'd expect typical ltr behaviour for the text, but when a `<select>` is inactive it seems there's a semantic argument over whether or not the rules of the selected `<option>` still apply. Feel free to browse the relevant RFCs but whatever you find, good luck persuading Mozilla they got it wrong.

I'd say you have two options: don't restrict the width of the `<select>` in which case it'll expand to fit the text, or don't use a `<select>` element - build what you want with `<div>`s, CSS and Javascript. Neither solution is ideal perhaps, but I don't see one that is, to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i think it's a problem not a decision of Mozzilla.
My problem is that some users going with Chrome and see correct and some with Firefox and say that won't be accepted...

Comment: In fact it's Chrome that's being inconsistent here. It may be that it's doing what you want, but in fact it's contradicting its own usual behaviour. The `direction: ltr` on the `option_class` is what's making it look the way you want, but for the most part styles on an `<option>` element don't apply when the `<select>` is inactive. For example, try applying a different `font-style` or `color` to `option-class`. You'll see it doesn't affect the `<select>` itself, just the options in the dropdown. So the chances are, Firefox has it right and your only option is to use `<div>`s etc.

Comment: Damn, then i can set the rtl opening, the ltr showing in option list but i can't work on the selected item :(
Thanks for the explain, i think i'll search a way with Jquery / Js / other system then

Answer (score 1):

Try this and just set your width to auto and then if needed align text accordingly, remove direction from your .option_class to align text.

```
.select_class {
 width:auto;
 direction: rtl;
 text-align:left;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but now the select opens from left to right :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `text-overflow: ellipsis;` from `.select_class` css.

Comment: This won't resolve nothing, the problem is not the ellipsis, the problem is that firefox won't show the "start of the text" but align to right while selected

Comment: I am not sure if you can change the direction of the text that way. I think it is a bug of firefox. I thought you were talking about the 3 dots.

Answer (score 0):

@Luca Black Please do following.

```
.select_class {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: auto;
}
```

please remove width size 150px and put auto. your issue resolved in firefox browser.

Comment: I can't remove "width:150px" i need to respect that size it's for a table, i know without that will work ^^

Comment: @LucaBlack change direction `rtl` to `ltr` that will resolve your issue.

Comment: no... test before posting pls...
Just tested and it won't help

Comment: The start of the post is 
" i want to make a select that opens from right to left."